# cannot resolve symbol split in spark job

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm running a spark application on my IntelliJ IDE as a Maven Project,
I'm trying to create a rowRDD and convert them to dataframe and store it in hdfs.

> SPARK VERSION : 1.5.2
>   SCALA VERSION: 2.10.4

My code:

```
val rowRDD= dataframename.map(_.split("\t")).map(p => Row(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3)))
```

It reports value split is not a member of my class package AND reports application does not take any parameters.

There is some dependency issue and I need help on that.

*Note: I'm done with schema defenition for rowRDD*

Thanks for supporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spark DataFrame Documentation:

```
map[R](f: (Row) ⇒ R)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[R]): RDD[R]
"Returns a new RDD by applying a function to all rows of this DataFrame."
```

So when you call `map` on a DF, you are mapping over `Row` objects which do not have a `split` method.

See [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is mentioned in spark documentation that map.split method can be used. check this link:  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

Comment: In that example they are calling `map` on `people` which is an `RDD[String]`. Unless `dataframename` is also `RDD[String]`, you will not be able to call `split` like they are.

Comment: They can call `split` because they are mapping over `String`s which have a `split` method